# Choose a random element from an array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, elementor

I want to randomly choose between 1 and 50 Pokemons, but `rand` chooses only the 42nd one of the array (Dragonite). How can I make it be random?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    char sorteio1[50][11] = {"Bulbasaur","Venusaur","Charmander","Charmeleon","Charizard","Pidgey","Pidgeotto","Pidgeot","Pikachu","Raichu","Clefairy","Vulpix","Ninetales","Meowth","Psyduck","Golduck","Mankey","Primeape","Growlithe","Arcanine","Abra","Kadabra","Alakazam","Magnemite","Magneton","Onix","Cubone","Marowak","Staryu","Starmie","MrMime","Jynx","Magikarp","Gyarados","Lapras","Ditto","Eevee","Vaporeon","Porygon","Snorlax","Dragonair","Dragonite","Mewtwo","Mew","Chikorita","Sentret","Furret","Hoothoot","Lanturn","Pichu"};
    int i;

    i = rand() %50;

    printf ("%s\n",sorteio1[i]);    

    system ("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This site is in English, perhaps you want [Stack Overflow em Português](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/)?

Comment: I can't tell whether that is Spanish or Portuguese. You might want to post that at https://es.stackoverflow.com/ or https://pt.stackoverflow.com/.

Answer (score 0):

You should seed your random number - you can use the current time to give you different inputs.

Check [srand documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/srand/).

The example from the documentation:

```
/* srand example */
#include <stdio.h>      /* printf, NULL */
#include <stdlib.h>     /* srand, rand */
#include <time.h>       /* time */

int main ()
{
  printf ("First number: %d\n", rand()%100);
  srand (time(NULL));
  printf ("Random number: %d\n", rand()%100);
  srand (1);
  printf ("Again the first number: %d\n", rand()%100);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is this the only way to get this right? I don't know if I'll be allowed to use time.h

Comment: Time is only used to get you a seed that changes all the time. If you find another way of generating a seed that is different each time you run the program, you can replace this call (maybe asking the user to type a number for the seed)...

Comment: By the way, this site is in english - I edited your question to be on-topic here. You should accept it before you get too many downvotes or it gets closed

Comment: @LeonardoAlvesMachado Pleae flag/vote to close obvious dupes.  This question has been asked many a time.